# Error Trigger : Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I wrote this trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_expirationDate
AFTER INSERT ON DIFFUSION FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    lastdiffusion DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(diffusionDate) INTO lastdiffusion FROM DIFFUSION WHERE idEpisode = :NEW.idEpisode;
    UPDATE EPISODE SET expirationDate = lastdiffusion + 14 WHERE idEpisode = :NEW.idEpisode;
END;
/
```

The compilation is OK, but when I insert some values in DIFFUSION, I have the following error :

```
ORA-04091: table DIFFUSION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

I don't see what is the problem..

Can someone help me and tell me what i am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314769/how-to-avoid-table-mutating-errors/40317580#40317580) a few days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing the table being updated in the trigger itself.  Oracle gets confused.  And, if you think about this hard enough, you'll probably also get confused.

Fortunately, in this case, I don't think you need to reference the table.  Instead, just use logic on the `update`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_expirationDate
AFTER INSERT ON DIFFUSION FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE EPISODE
        SET expirationDate = :NEW.diffusionDate + 14
        WHERE idEpisode = :NEW.idEpisode AND
              expirationDate < :NEW.diffusionDate + 14;
END;
```

That is, only update `expirationDate` when the value is going to change.  If you do this for every insert, then it will always be the maximum value.

Comment: Thank you ! It is exactly what i was triying to do

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use the same table of the trigger in another query this cause a redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Use compound trigger,it solves your problem.

[This article](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html#:%7E:text=A%20mutating%20table%20error%20%28ORA,which%20the%20trigger%20was%20fired) contains more info.

Comment: Could you apply the knowledge from the link to the problem in your answer?  Otherwise this should rather be a comment on the question rather than an answer.