# Values of the inserted row in a Trigger Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I want a trigger that updates the value of a column, but I just want to update a small set of rows that depends of the values of the inserted row.
My trigger is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE table1 t
SET column2 = 3
WHERE t.column1 = :new.column1;
END;
/
```

But as I using FOR EACH ROW I have a problem when I try it, I get the mutating table runtime error.
Other option is not to set the FOR EACH ROW, but if I do this, I dont know the inserted "column1" for comparing (or I dont know how to known it).

What can I do for UPDATING a set of rows that depends of the last inserted row?

I am using Oracle 9.

Comment: I once wrote the values in a work-table in the FOR EACH ROW TRIGGER and in the after-tabe trigger i handled the values selected from the work-table.

Comment: Strongly suggest you follow @GordonLinoff's advice below. This is not a good data model.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid the DML statements on the same table as defined in a trigger. Use `before` DML to change values of the current table.

```
create or replace trigger example
before insert on table1
for each row
begin
    :new.column2 := 3;
end;
/
```

You can modify the same table with pragma autonomous_transaction:

```
create or replace trigger example
after insert on table1 for each row
declare
    procedure setValues(key number) is
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
        update table1 t
        set column2 = 3
        where t.column1 = key
        ;
    end setValues;    
begin
    setValues(:new.column1);
end;
/
```

But I suggest you follow @GordonLinoff answere to your question - it's a bad idea to modify the same table in the trigger body.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314769/how-to-avoid-table-mutating-errors/40317580#40317580)

Comment: This is the correct way to write a trigger in Oracle, but unfortunately this won't resolve the issue since the OP wants to update more than one row at a time.

Comment: The solution is in the link I included in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update multiple rows in `table1` when you are updating one row, then you would seem to have a problem with the data model.

This need suggests that you need a separate table with one row per `column1`. You can then fetch the value in that table using `join`. The trigger will then be updating *another* table, so there will be no mutation problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
`create table A 
 (
  a INTEGER,
  b CHAR(10)
 );
 create table B
 (
  b CHAR (10),
  d INTEGER 
 );
 create trigger trig1
 AFTER INSERT ON A
 REFERENCING NEW AS newROW
 FOR EACH ROW
 when(newROW.a<=10)
 BEGIN 
 INSERT into B values(:newROW.b,:newROW.a);
 END trig1;
 insert into A values(11,'Gananjay');
 insert into A values(5,'Hritik');

 select * from A;
 select * from B;`
```